# Listening for Database Changes on a Webserver via Java?

Tags: java, php, sockets, notifications

I have web application in PHP which changes a database if the user does a specific action.

Additionally there runs a Java app for the ui. Whenever the database value of a specific user is changed, the Java app should get notified via PHP.

My idea is to use Firebase Cloud Messaging. This implies that the user registers in the Java app and the FCM id is linked to the Java App. Another way might be to implement a socket via PHP and connect to Java app to it and waiting for socket messages. A third way might be polling the data every x seconds. This seems to be no good way.

What is the recommended way to listen for database updates in a Java app? Might there be a problem for socket connections (e.g. limited to 10.000) or is it unlimited?

Answer (score 0):

1. 

If you can access the PHP code, a simple solution is:

You can create a java HTTP REST server that you call from PHP when needed.

2)
If you want more flexibility, scalability

You can use a JMS midleware between PHP and Java, that can provide a two way communication. See rabbitMQ or activeMQ
You still need to access PHP code to send messages to the midleware. Java listenning througth the midleware to receiving messages

3)
If you can't access PHP side, there still have this solution:

You can use a tool like debezium to listen to database changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like a Publisher/Subscriber problem, I would use AMQP (such as RabbitMQ, Kafka):

The PHP app can publish `specificAction` events to an exchange, and the Java app can subscribe to those events by binding a queue to that exchange. This increases decoupling and availability.

Note - there's a small portion of databases that support Change Streams (like MongoDB), which lets you listen to data changes.